# Conditinal sentence put gap

Tags: grammar, conditional-constructions

Sentence:

Madina is allergic to honey.If she  _____ (eat)honey,her tongue _____  (to get inflamed).

I filled gaps with "eats" and "will get".
And rigth anwser was "eats" and "gets inflamed" is this right?

Answer (score 1):

Both are right, but the meanings are slightly different.

> If she eats honey, her tongue will get inflamed.

This fits when pondering a specific event that might occur at a certain time in the future.

> If she eats honey, her tongue gets inflamed.

This is a statement about Madina *in general* without reference to any specific event. It is more detached and definitely the more common idiomatic way to express the idea.

Also, "to get inflamed" sounds weird to me - I think "to swell up" is much more idiomatic, as in "If she eats honey, her tongue swells up."